# Mod Rewrite / .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was wondering if there is a shorter version for this:

RewriteRule ^signup$ /signup.php [L]
RewriteRule ^signup/$ /signup.php [L]

Thank for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes.

```
RewriteRule ^signup(/)?$ /signup.php [L]
```